# React filter by category feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, gallery, infinite-loop

Hello I am building photo gallery where I would like to add feature that user will be able filter by Category. I tried some solutions but there are two bugs that I am not able to fix. First is that if I go to the GalleryPage (using Swtich) it does NOT render dynamically added buttons from FilterButton component. I have to click one more time on the link and then it DOES render the buttons. I dont know why it does not work on the first render.

Other issue is that I am able to filter by category but it causes the infinite loop in the useEffect and I dont know how to fix it.

I have got GalleryPage component where I am getting data from API and parsing the data for using later in other components. Here it seems that is all working fine.

```
const GalleryPage = () => {
    const url = 'someurl';
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('All');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(url,);
            setData(result.data)
            result.data.forEach(item => {
                imageUrl.push(item.image)
                if (categoryList.indexOf(item.group) === -1) { 
                      categoryList.push(item.group)
                }
            })
         }
         fetchData();
         }, [])       

    return (
       <FilterButton setCategory={setCategory} categoryList={categoryList}/>
       <Gallery data={data} category={category}/>
    )
}
```

If I go to the GalleryPage the h3 and 'All' button is rendered. But I have to click on the link one more time to render the buttons inside the map function:

```
const FilterButton = ({setCategory, categoryList}) => {
    return(
        <h3>Gallery</h3>
        <button onClick={()=> setCategory('All')}>All</button>
        {categoryList.map(item => (
           <button key={item} onClick={()=> setCategory(item)}>{item}</button>
        ))}
     )

};

export default FilterButton;
```

And here I am not able to fix the infinite loop:

```
const Gallery = ({data, category}) => {
    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        let temp = []
        if (category === 'All'){
            setPhotos(data)          
        }else{
            data.map(item => {
               temp.push(item)
            })
        }
        setPhotos(temp)
    }) 
    return(
       photos.map((item => 
           <img key={item.id} src={item.image}/>
       ))
    )
};

export default Gallery;
```

If I add empty array to the useEffect it does not work at all. Also I am using styled components and framer motion but it should not have affect on this I hope.

Comment: You don't push to `categoryList`, it's immutable, you need to change the state, 
for example `setCategoryList([...categoryList, item.group])`,  first filter the data and then use `setCategoryList` to change its state

Comment: @zb22 I changed in the GalleryPage  the `categoryList.push(item.group)` to `setCategoryList([...categoryList, item.group])` but it adds only last value to the array.

Answer (score 0):

First, I see that you're never setting your state for categoryList.
After modifying categoryList, you should call `setCategoryList()` with the new category list. This way, the state variable will be 'remembered' when the component is re-rendered.
You can read about the useState hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Additionally, for the useEffect hook, the 'empty array' you pass in at the end is actually an array of variables to 'watch' for changes. If you pass an empty array, the useEffect will only run once, at the first page load. However, you can pass in something like `[category]` so that the useEffect is only called when the `category` variable is modified, which I persume is what you want to do.

Comment: I tried that, but it wont render any images when page loads. I have to change the state of `category` and then it renders it.

Comment: Could be because you initialize your `category` state to an empty array? 
Try initializing it with something like `useState('All');`

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. init state of category is 'All' I updated the code so it there.